# sending files from node.js to node.js server

Tags: sockets, node.js

Whats the best way to send large files from one node.js server to another? We tried to encode it with base64 and send it over an allready existent tls socket connection, but the base64 string is to long so the socket splits it in several parts. We also thought to send it via http methods but that seems not the best way for us. Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with HTTP in your use case?

Comment: its just a beauty thing, we have to start a http server and cannot use our existing socket connection between both servers...

Comment: Isn't it beneficial to use an additional socket connection? Not knowing what your first socket is doing, it might be still better to use another socket for high volume network I/O and do the transmission out-of-band.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there are no special requirements, I'd use HTTP. HTTP cliens and servers are both available and rather mature in node.js, and HTTP gives you additional features (i.e. Caching, optimistic transactional behaviour, content negotiation, partial requests, etc.).

Don't roll your own protocol based on plain sockets, you are reinventing the wheel. But you might consider other protocols such as FTP as well.